# Find a file in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, windows, filesystem

So My friend wanted to play Grand fantasia with him so I had downloaded it previously on windows, once the windows broke and I went to ubuntu I wanted to try and install it onto ubuntu thinking I could try and work it on wine and if it didn't I could just uninstall it from the folder on my desktop, in the end it didn't work and now I have to hunt it down but I can't find it, It's one point four gig and I need help finding it it said it installed on the c drive but I don't know where to start or how the filing system works on ubuntu. If it helps I have ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: i have a 64 bit, but I don't even know how to get to the program files on ubuntu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you installed it finally under `wine` , if so, the check:

`ls ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/`